# If $A \in M_n(R)$ be diagonizable with $tr(A^2)=0$ show A is the zero matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace

**If $A \in M_n(R)$ be diagonalizable with $\operatorname{\mathbf{tr}}(A^2)=0$ show $A$ is the zero matrix**

If $\operatorname{tr}(A^2)=0$ then $\sum a_{i,i}^2+\sum2a_{i,j}a_{j,i}=0$

We also have $A^2=CDC^{-1}CDC^{-1}=CD^2C^{-1}$
$$\operatorname{tr}(A^2)=\operatorname{tr}(CD^2C^{-1})$$
$$0=\operatorname{tr}(A^2)=\operatorname{tr}(C^{-1}CD^2) = \operatorname{tr}(D^2)$$

But I'm not sure what to do with this information

Comment: think about the eigenvalues and how they relate to the trace

Comment: or, since you already wrote it, write down what is the trace of $D^2$

Comment: The matrix $((i,0),(0,1))$ satisfies your condition and is not zero.

Comment: @Exodd its just 0 but how can I show that A is a 0 matrix?

Comment: @JCAA the matrices have entries in $\mathbb R$ and are diagonalizable in $\mathbb R$

Comment: The last part is not in the OP.

Comment: @Exodd I guess if the trace on D^2 = 0 that would make $\sum \lambda^2 = 0 $meaning all the lambdas are 0?

Comment: @JCAA it is quite a standard convention. If you specify the field where the entries lie, then the matrix is intended to be diagonalizable in that field, unless differently specified.

Comment: @JohnRawls exactly

Comment: @Exodd but how would that demonstrate that A is a 0 matrix tho?

Comment: @JohnRawls $\lambda$ are the diagonal entries of $D$, and $A = CDC^{-1}$, so...

Comment: @Exodd loooooooool

Comment: Add it to the question (your standard convention is not that standard). If it is diagonalizable over the  reals, then the sum of squares of real  eigenvalues is 0, hence all eigenvalues are 0 and the matrix is similar to the zero matrix, so it is the zero matrix itself.